# Getting a small string out of big html (REGEXP)

Tags: javascript, php, regex, expression

im searching somebody who he realy good with regexp.

Look at this html code:

```
<div class="market_listing_table_header">
        <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price market_sortable_column">PRICE<span class="market_sort_arrow" style="display:none;"> ?</span></div>
        <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings market_sortable_column">QUANTITY<span class="market_sort_arrow" style="display:none;"> ?</span></div>
                <div class="market_sortable_column"><span class="market_listing_header_namespacer"></span>NAME<span class="market_sort_arrow" style="display:none;"> ?</span></div>
    </div>

<a class="market_listing_row_link" href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Sticker%20Capsule">
    <div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult" id="result_0">
                <img id="result_0_image" src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/oPg27gVBfBTgdCk41FdRyxi0_F9BMXJUNLr6IjCxGWxp8wEVXF06BkCtNcbyNw1FALOnGEguclAysf0wMacOZmaxBh9KSCcNe-A32vprQ1YCofxKJG0pUDK19jFBsgxqY65AVBsNeAcUtDXMqyxeURPzuhkdLW5bM7yic3-mCD9s-EhOGgl7VUa3YZCxaAJS/62fx62f" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="">      
                <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
            <span class="market_table_value">
                Starting at:<br>
                <span style="color:white">$10.03 USD</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings">
            <span class="market_table_value">
                <span class="market_listing_num_listings_qty">568,694</span>
            </span>
        </div>

                <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
            <span id="result_0_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #D2D2D2;">Sticker Capsule</span>
            <br>
            <span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

<a class="market_listing_row_link" href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/CS%3AGO%20Weapon%20Case%203">
    <div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult" id="result_1">
                <img id="result_1_image" src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/S7adkJSkWAGxsBVYqLRazfP6VyHQ1FZBZX7GQkxSEmqCvaprzbgeExFpCaaO1AZD6_0MZtnLVkVjdcFQTUQFYI3_rWHbrQMYKiQLuoaISFDp71c0tY0YQHZ_8BBMQ1I2h7PoNtvtWk9MdlP91Z5fB6LtFDPZzU1ON36aG1UXUzzXtbwyi_McGBI=/62fx62f" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="">      
                <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
            <span class="market_table_value">
                Starting at:<br>
                <span style="color:white">$0.04 USD</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings">
            <span class="market_table_value">
                <span class="market_listing_num_listings_qty">233,789</span>
            </span>
        </div>

                <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
            <span id="result_1_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #D2D2D2;">CS:GO Weapon Case 3</span>
            <br>
            <span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

I need this part: (the bold one)

$**0.03** USD

and i need it every time something is between

Starting at: < span style="color:white"> AND < /span>

Does somebody knows a tip for me?

Kind Regards,
Freddy

Comment: Magic ? I don't see anything mate..

Comment: I looked, and I didn't see anything, then again regex isn't my thing, so maybe somebody who he realy good can see something.

Comment: @adeneo, this was a good one ;)

Comment: lol :D guys your to fast =) now there should be something! :D

Comment: I wouldn't RegExp it at all - you're pulling data from a Steam Marketplace feed by the looks of it - therefore it should be structured. Work out the structure and use DOMDocument and DOMXPath to find the data you're after - trying to match on a `span` with a given style is never going to be reliable : http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I would do this with jQuery (or even standard JS), not regex (and I **love** regex).

Comment: Thx talemyn! I did it with DomDoc! NICE! :D I like it! (y) Works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/<span style="color:white">.*?([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?).*?<\/span>/
```

The first group will contain what you want.

Comment: preg_match_all('<span style="color:white">.*?([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?).*?</span>' , $html , $matches);
print_r($matches);

this doenst work! Did i anything wrong?

Comment: this doesnt work for me. I get 36 as result every time :O Thank You anyway